# SparkClassNotFoundException: [DATA_SOURCE_NOT_FOUND] Failed to find data source: dbc

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, datasource, classnotfoundexception, databricks-community-edition

I am using DataBricks Community Edition
Here is the code:
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AgXM.png)

It seems tht Spark cannot read or process the .dbc file format. I have this error:

org.apache.spark.SparkClassNotFoundException: [DATA_SOURCE_NOT_FOUND] Failed to find data source: dbc. Please find packages at `https://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html`.

Based on my searches for a fix, I need to install a package that supports the .dbc file. The problem is i don't know which package. Unless there are other solutions aside from installing a package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.dbc` file extension is used for storing Databricks notebooks, it's not something that you will need to open using Spark. If you need to open it, use the Import menu item to pull it into the Databricks workspace.  See [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/en/notebooks/notebook-export-import.html) for more details about notebooks.

Comment: I realized I've been importing it wrong. Thank you very much.